# How can docker help software automation testers?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, docker

How can docker help automation testers?

I know it provides linux containers which is similar to virtual machines but how can I use those containers in software automation testing.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

You can use Docker to easily create an isolated, reproducible and portable environment for testing. Every dependency goes to an image and whenever you need an environment to test your application you just run some images.

## Long answer

### Applications have a lot of dependencies

A typical application has a lot of dependencies to other system. You might have a database, a LDAP, a Memcache or a many more things your system depends on. The application itself needs a certain run time (Java, Python, Ruby) in a dedicated version (Java 7 or Java 8). You might also need a server (Tomcat, Jetty, NGINX) with settings for your application. You might need a special folder structure for your application and so on.

### Setting up an test environment becomes complicated

All this things make up the environment you need for your application. You need this environment to run your application in production, to develop it and to test it (manual or automated). This environment can become quite complicated and maintaining it will cost you a lot of time and trouble.

### Dependencies become images

This is where Docker comes into play: Docker let's you put your database (with the initial data of your application already set up) to a Docker image. The same goes for your LDAP, your Memcache and all other applications you depend on. Docker let's you even package your own application into an image which provides the correct run time, server, folder structure and configuration.

### Images make your environment easily reproducible

Those images are self-contained, isolated and portable. This means you can pull them on every machine and just run them as they are. Instead of installing a database, LDAP, Memcache and configure all of them you just pull the images and run them. This makes it super easy to spin up a new and fresh environment in seconds whenever you need.

### Testing becomes easier

And that's the basic for your tests, because you would need a clean, fresh and reproducible environment to perform tests against. Especially "reproducible" and "fresh" is important. If you run automated tests (locally on the developer maschine or on your build server) you must use the *same* environment. Otherwise your tests are not reliable. Fresh is important because it means you can just stop all containers when your tests are finished and every data mess your tests created is gone. When you run your tests again you just spin up a new enviroment which is clean and in its initial state.

Comment: Do docker images get stored in somewhere central repository similar to Git,SVN? How can I pull the containers on other machines?

Comment: You can store Docher images in a Docker Registry. There is an official one for public images at https://registry.hub.docker.com, but you can also install your own private registry (see https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying). On the machine where you build the image you would "push" it to the registry and on another machine you can "pull" it from the registry. Very much like GIT and SVN are doing it for code.